# Outlook 2013 Execute Insert Signature

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, signature

I have been tasked with upgrading our company add-in for Outlook to make it compatible with Outlook 2013. It currently works fine in Outlook 2007 and 2010.  The problem that I'm running into has to do with how CommandBars are no longer supported in 2013.

For example, the below snippet will find Insert/Signature, and then execute the button for the signature menu-entry that matches the name we're looking for.

```
  objCBP = (Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarPopup)inspector.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.FindControl(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 30005);
  if ( objCBP != null ) {
      objCBP2 = (Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarPopup)objCBP.CommandBar.FindControl(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 5608);
      if ( objCBP2 != null) {
           colCBControls = objCBP2.Controls;
           if ( colCBControls != null) {
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton objCBB in colCBControls) {
                    if ( objCBB.Caption == SignatureName )  {
                         objCBB.Execute();
                    }
                }
           }
       }
  }
```

Unfortunately, this does NOT work for Outlook 2013.

So, here's my question/problem:

From our add-in button, how can I get it to execute the exact MS code to insert the given signature? We've tried ExecuteMso as well, with no luck ( Invalid argument Exception, trying both "SignatureInsertMenu" and "SignatureGallery" ).

It seems silly that Microsoft killed-off and buried this functionality that worked just fine for 2007 and 2010.

Additionally, I understand that I can "embed" the original MS signature button into our RibbonMenu by specifying IdMso = "SignatureInsertMenu" ... but then there doesn't appear to be a way to change the Microsoft Icon to our Signature ICON, which matches the rest of the buttons on our custom Ribbon menu. (trying to keep a consistent look/feel to our menu buttons).

I'm looking for either solution.

1) Either a way to change the ICON on the Microsoft Signature button to be our image
   (specifically on our addins Ribbon menu, not effecting the real MS button)

2) A way to execute the code/methods already built-into Outlook 2013 so that when someone 
   clicks OUR menu, it executes the Microsoft insert signature code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With Outlook 2013/Outlook 2016 I didn't find any evidance of a real API. Even with Redemption I couldn't access the dropdown (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991107/invoke-3rd-party-outlook-addin-button-from-my-addin/34747406#34747406)).
Currently we consider this hacky way: Using SendKeys to "find" the SignatureMenu (there are shortcuts) and {DOWN} to select a specific signature and {ENTER}.
It is really stupid, but all other options (create a new Email and copy over the content) seems also crazy and has it's own flaws.