# Invoke 3rd party Outlook AddIn-Button from my AddIn

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-redemption

I'm looking to create an AddIn for outlook which will invoke an Attach and Forward function from another 3rd party addIn when a mail item is added to a certain folder, however I'm not sure how to find this button in order to invoke it.
the desired button is displayed on the inbox screen (when mail is selected bottom left) but not when a mail is opened (double click) is in a drop-down, here's the structure. Highlighted is the desired function.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: control]

How would I invoke this function for a specific mail item I found the Redemption Library which seems useful but not sure how fully to apply it.
[Invoke Ribbon button in Outlook 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546860/invoke-ribbon-button-in-outlook-2013)

This is what I have so far. See comments. (snippet from @Dmitry Streblechenko)

```
private void ExecuteAttachAndForward()
    {
    Redemption.SafeInspector sInspector = new Redemption.SafeInspector();
    sInspector.Item = Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
    Redemption.SafeRibbon Ribbon = sInspector.Ribbon;
    string oldActiveTab = Ribbon.ActiveTab;
    Ribbon.ActiveTab = "Home";   // is this the correct name of the tab?         
    Redemption.SafeRibbonControl Control = Ribbon.Controls.Item("Attach and Forward"); 
    // how would I access the pdf sub function in the dropdown?
    Control.Execute();
    Ribbon.ActiveTab = oldActiveTab; //restore the active tab                          
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the control that you are trying to invoke?

Comment: Added screenshot to OP

Comment: The best you can do is simulate a click on the "Attach and Forward" button...

Comment: Is it not possible to select one of the options in the dropdown??

Comment: I don't think so - as far as I remember the items are not visible to the Accessibility API until the button is clicked and the dropdown is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way: Invoke the Ribbon via Redemption and use [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx).SendWait("{DOWN}{ENTER}");

Actually this seems to work pretty well.